# DELETE else UPDATE from temp table

Tags: merge, teradata

This may seem easy but I have been looking for some hours now.

How do I insert rows in a target table that do not exist in the temp table,
and at the same time delete rows in the target table that do exist in the temp table? It has to be transaction secure, in teradata, and if possible performant.

MERGE does not support delete and insert at the same time apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Along with temporary/work table, you can make use of BTET to make delete and insert transaction safe. 
Sample example shown below

```
CREATE TABLE temp_Table_2 AS (SELECT * FROM target_Table WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM temp_Table WHERE target_Table.key_cols = temp_Table.key_cols)) WITH DATA;

BT;

--First delete rows which are present in temp table
DELETE FROM target_Table WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM temp_Table WHERE target_Table.key_cols = temp_Table.key_cols);

--Second Insert rows which were not exist in target table 
INSERT INTO target_Table
col_1,
col_1,
.
.
col_n
)
SELECT 
col_1,
col_1,
.
.
col_n
 FROM temp_Table
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM temp_Table_2 WHERE temp_Table_2.key_cols = temp_Table.key_cols);

ET;

DROP TABLE temp_Table_2;
```

Note: You can tweak the example if there is any third table from where you want to INSERT rows into target table that do not exists in Temp table

Comment: The INSERT should be coded as MERGE because this might be more efficient (avoiding spool). And instead of BT/ET a MultiStatement can be used.

Comment: Thanks Dnoeth, MultiStatement seems better idea than BT/ET.

Comment: But a multistatement is not transaction secure, or?

Comment: And also, is a MERGE more efficient than a simple INSERT...SELECT? How is that possible?

Comment: oh and finally you would also be inserting the rows that you wanted to just delete ;)

Comment: @Rusty75: A MultiStatement is an implicit transaction, no need for BT/ET. Merge can be more efficient because it might work without an intermediate spool. The logic is coded correctly, there's a 2nd `temp_table_2`